# Dockerfile CMD for pipeline base image

Tags: dockerfile, kubeflow-pipelines

I was writing a Docker for generating base image for my Kubeflow pipeline, so the purpose is just to install python package in the image. There isn't a command that I want to run. As a CMD/ENTRYPOINT is needed in a Dockerfile, what kind of command should I execute for my use case?